# tool to scan ruby code files for repeating or similar code chunks

Tags: ruby, dry

Is there a way to scan ruby files for repeating code?

I have almost 30 files each between 200-1000 lines of  code and I need to optimize and refactor them.

I was thinking of moving repeated code to a utility class that can be used across all files.

Is there some kind of scanning tool to easily find and mark chunks of repeated or similar code?

Or am I just going to have to bite the proverbial bullet and do it by hand?

Comment: Can you narrow down your requirements here a little? A concrete example of what you're trying to find would help. Does the code differ by indentation? By variable names? Doing it by hand is usually the most reliable way, automatic detection only catches copy-paste jobs. Ruby's "Don't Repeat Yourself" methodology involves careful analysis and reduction of code to its essentials.

Comment: Methods that are mostly the same, or stretches of repeated code that kind of thing. Isn't there a code tool like rubocop for helping to dry up code?

Comment: There's tools like [CodeClimate](https://codeclimate.com) and Rubocop, absolutely. If you have stretches of repeated code it sounds like your development process is total anarchy. How does any of that pass a code review?

Comment: When I'm not the one doing the coding. It was coded in what appears to be a slapdash manner by a really junior developer.

After fixing a few bugs and adding few features one of my next tasks is to start optimising the job scripts, so I want to know how much is repeated across the files so I can dry it up by centralising it into a utility class. 

Let's just say I my first thought on it was "why dear god, why?".

That said and done though, it does work.

Comment: You need to clarify what you mean by "repeating code". If one file contains the line `"x = 3"` in two places, is that repeating code? If two files each contain lines `"x = 3"`, is that repeating code? Have you considered just rewriting the code? Patching crappy code can be a big time-waster in the long-run.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: One can define clones carefully, enabling a mechanical engine to find them.   CloneDR defines a clone as 2 or more code blocks of code that meet similarity criteria, found in any designated set of files:  at least a certain minimum size (nobody cares about 3 character clones), not differing more than K places.  See "detection parameters" in my answer.

Comment: @Ira, that's fine, but the OP still needs to define what he or she means by "repeating code".

Comment: @CarySwoveland:  "repeating code" == "clone".  OP can control the definition by providing the parameter values, unless OP means something else.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can look at *flay*: https://github.com/seattlerb/flay
From the docs:

> Flay analyzes code for structural similarities. Differences in literal
>   values, variable, class, method names, whitespace, programming style,
>   braces vs do/end, etc are all ignored. Making this totally rad.

Or, depending on your budget, you can create an account with one of the hosted static code analysis services and push your code there for a checkup.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you sir, please have a cookie!

P.s. I'm sooo going to run flog on those scripts and just see how painful the code really is.

Comment: If you are looking for more static code checks, look at: flay, flog, reek, rubocop, and more from this list: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/code_metrics

or just check MetricFu which combines various metrics. And thanks for the cookie:-)

Answer (score 2):

Our [CloneDR](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Clone/) tool can do this; we are just finishing one up for Ruby.  It hunts for duplicate code that matches a set of constraints (on size, # points of variation, similarity of the matching part/total, etc.).

Here are samples of a CloneDR run against most of the Metasploit code base.
That's about 460K SLOC of Ruby code; (at least) 14% of the code base is clones.

The first picture below is the summary page.  The second is an example detected clone (one of some 3000 found in that code base); you might want to click on this picture in your browser and use the "+" button to make it a bit larger and easier to see.

[image: Summary Page from Ruby CloneDR run]

[image: Example Ruby Clone]

Comment: Nice! should be super useful when hunting for code to re-factor.